# Is it safe to delete Selenium.log from my CentOS server?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, centos, master-slave

It seems that I've run out of room on my Master node and I need to clear some space in order to reboot my daily tests. Selenium.log is taking up a lot of space and I'm convinced its not currently being used. Would it be safe to delete?

Edit: I deleted the file and upon starting a new build Selenium created a new log file. I didn't experience any issues during this new build either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what creates the file, or where it is, but assuming that you can already see the important details from each build in the Jenkins UI (e.g. in the console log, or in test results etc.), then you shouldn't need to keep any files that are sitting in the workspace or elsewhere.